# Remove the dagger and footnote from the Meta and Stack Apps FAQ regarding comment reputation

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, faq-update-request, stackapps, meta-faq

From the FAQ pages on both [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq) and [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/faq):

> **1**  Leave comments<sup>†</sup>
>   [...]
>   <sub><sup>†</sup> you can always comment on your questions and answers, and any answers to questions you've asked, even with 1 rep.</sub>

The dagger is useful on the other websites and as a default for Stack Exchange sites. However, when 1 reputation is all that is necessary to leave comments anywhere on those two sites, there's no real need to have the footnote there.

This is a fairly low priority request. I simply wanted to voice this in the light of Stack Apps being established.

**UPDATE**

Amidst other FAQ updates that Jeff seems to have just handled, the dagger and footnote have been removed. Gonna accept Jon's answer for now, unless Jeff plans to post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would actually call this a feature request.

All the reputation levels (I assume) come from some kind of configuration setting. So this would be a dynamic behaviour of hiding the message when that particular setting equals 1.

Given that, I'm not sure it's worth the effort to remove the message, but yeah, I agree it's a little strange.

Comment: This is a low-priority faq-update-request, definitely, but I wanted to voice it now, since Stack Apps was recently setup. I wouldn't make the process automated, though. Since the FAQ writer is free to write on whatever portions are desired (hence the differences in the explanations on how reputation is earned), I figure it's just simpler to remove it at whatever time it becomes convenient to do so.